# Find the Closed form of $\sum_{i=0}^k {{2k+2}\choose{i}} (2k)^i$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, combinations

I am trying to solve an integer equation which involves the expression
$$\sum_{i=0}^k \binom{2k+2}{i}(2k)^i,$$
where $k\in\mathbb{N}$. It would be helpful if there exists a closed form for this expression.

Any ideas as to how I could achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try the binomial theorem?

Comment: Apologies, I suggested an edit with plenty of mistakes (or completely mistakes).